# How to save Japanese and Korean characters in a Word 2010 VBA export?

Tags: vba, microsoft-word-2010

I have a *Word 2010* document with a 3-column table. The rows have closed caption texts for use in an instructional video. Example row:

[image]

I am running a *VBA* sub to save the captions in each of the three languages to a separate **.vtt** (text) file that will be referenced inside the *Video* tag in the *.html* page.

The problem is that the Japanese and Korean captions are saved as a row of question marks: ?????????????????????

Relevant code extracts:

`Open "d:\dropbox\Japanese.vtt" For Output As #1
Set rngTable = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=TableCell.Range.Start, 
End:=TableCell.Range.End - 1)
Print #1, rngTable.Text`

What can I do to produce the correct output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a unicode file and use unicode-safe functions to emit the text.

From [Microsoft documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265018(v=vs.60).aspx)

```
Sub CreateAfile
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set a = fs.CreateTextFile("c:\testfile.txt", True, True)
    a.WriteLine("This is a test.")
    a.Close
End Sub
```

The form is `fs.CreateTextFile(filename(string), Overwrite(boolean), Unicode(boolean))`

I think you can use either `fs.write` or `fs.writeline`. Not sure if `Print #ff` is unicode safe. You may need to use [StrConv()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263373(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: I think his Word document is already unicode, the error occurs by "Print #1, rngTable.Text" ? I mean, in the document are alredy Japanese and Korean characters and they are correct showed, aren't they?

Comment: Above my pay grade, I am afraid. I rarely have to deal with non-latin characters, and encoding is kind of a hairy mess unless you live in it. All I know for sure is that the "???" symptom is an encoding switch: either the file is not flagged in the headers, so the reader is guessing, or the encoding got mangled; and that not all functions support unicode.

Comment: I have seen some people use database library functions to work with encoding, rather than in-built string functions.